# HBase first time using, error connecting to local host

Tags: java, ssh, hbase

Deployed a "joynet hadoop smartmachine" to tinker with HBase. It came with everything installed. I SSH with PuTTY, I go to the executable like this /opt/local/bin/hbase shell. All is well, then I try to create my test table like this:

```
create 'test', 'cf'
```

A bunch of stuff happens, then this comes up:

```
ERROR zookeeper.CLientCnxnSOcketNIO: Unable to open socket to localhost/127.0.0.1:2181
```

After googling it, I came across someone on here saying to add something like this to my configuration file:

```
config.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "172.80.72.86");
```

I cannot find the configuration file I'm supposed to add this to. 
Other questions I have:

```
172.80.72.86
```

That is not my IP, that was just in an example I found. Is that IP address supposed to the the server's IP address or my own IP address? My Server IP is 165.225.130.251

How do I append that to the configuration file from the command line alone?

I'm completely new to this. Any help for this would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following property in hbase-site.xml(/etc/hbase/conf)

```
    <property>
            <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
            <value>IP-of-Zookeeper-Installed Machine</value>
    </property>
```